# Angular *ngFor using PIPE not working when looping throw object

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable, for-of-loop

```
API data {
  id: 1,
  date: "21/may/2020",
  name: "Server A",
  geo: "Europa",
  status: "online"
}

 ngOnInit {
   this.col = [
     {field: 'name', header: 'Server Name'},
     {field: 'geo',  header: 'Geography'},
     {field: 'status', header: 'Status'},
     {field: 'date', header: 'Date'}
   ]
}
```

I'm testing angular PrimeNG and I have an data-table, where I set the values for each table row manually, it works fine.

template

```
 <ng-template>
  <td>
    <tr>
      <td>{{rowData.name}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.geo}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.status}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.date | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}</td>
    </tr>
  <td>
  <ng-template>
```

I updated my template to dynamically loop through the object and set the data, how can I update my loop so I can insert the pipe when I render the "date" object.

```
 <td *ngFor="let col of column">
    {{rowData[col.field]}}
</td>
```

The above `{{rowData[col.field]}}` is working, but I not sure how to inside `*ngFor="let col of columns "` I can update only the col.date and add pipe into it.

This is what I trying but not successful, the baove is working but not the Pipe and also if I add keyvalue the tables data is not being displayed anymore.

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns | keyvalue">
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] !== 'date'"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] === 'date'"> {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}</ng-container>
</td>
```

Any suggestion or example I can look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question right, you want to apply pipe on the birthdate field, so you can do ,

```
 <td *ngFor="let data of object">
    {{data["birthdate"] | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy' }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use key value pipe like

```
<td *ngFor="let data of object | keyvalue">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.key !== 'birthdate'"> {{data.value}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="data.key === 'birthdate'"> {{data.value | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}</ng-container>
</td>
```